# Returns value of sequence to previous value

Tags: sql-server

There is a sequence that is incremented for producing an ID  and passing it as a parameter to another stored procedure, something like this inside a procedure:

```
 declare @ID int

 select @ID = next value for seq1

 execute proc_insert @ID = @ID,...
```

The problem come up when execution of `proc_insert` fails, so we want that the value of sequence returns to previous value.

How can resolve this issue?

Comment: Reseed identity, reset sequence. This is correct behaviour and gaps will occur.

Comment: I will myself hv to do experiment.but you should always write within Begin Trans in both places even if it do not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your scenario is exactly not clear.
May be UDF which generate sequnce accordingly suit you.

If you are using Sequence then you can do like this.

suppose my sequence is define as,

```
CREATE SEQUENCE [dbo].[CountBy1] 
 AS [bigint]
 START WITH 1
 INCREMENT BY 1
 MINVALUE -9223372036854775808
 MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807
 CACHE 
GO
```

Then your proc_insert should return output parameter indicating pass/fail,

declare @ID int
 select @ID= next value for seq1
 execute proc_insert @ID=@ID, @Outputparameter=@Outputparameter...
 --find here if proc_insert failed

```
if(@Outputparameter=0)-- 0 means failed
 begin
 declare @Sql varchar(2000)=
    'ALTER SEQUENCE dbo.CountBy1
    RESTART WITH '+@ID+''

    Exec(@Sql)
 end
```

you should properly use Begin Trans and take help of Begin Try.

Also you should use `sp_executesql`

Comment: Great, Thank you so much